# couldn't load model properly codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have loaded the 2 models on a function in a controller. In my first controller, loading both models works. Now, when I load the same models in the same order, my second controller makes an error which is thrown to ajax. When I delete the `user_model` - the first model, it works fine: ajax fires its success function.
How come it throws error when I try loading the `user_model`? It works perfectly fine on a different controller.

Here's the code of the constructor method in my second controller

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('friend_model');
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

}
```

It's the same constructor method that I used in my another controller.
the error I got from the $.ajax error function is parsererror.

Comment: add some code of the models and controllers...

Comment: What is the error?Put some code for better understand

Comment: are your both models in same directory of models or other

Comment: both models are in same directory

Answer (score 0):

You will load all models,libraries and helpers file in constructor in controller file

```
<?php
class usercontroller extends CI_Controller{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
  }
}
?>
```

it's works fine.